# How to add ArrayList to JsonObject in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

> PaymentDetails class

```
data class PaymentDetails(
val type:String,
val bank: String,
val branch: String,
val account_no: String,
val cheque_date:String,
val return_type:Boolean,
val cheque_no:String,
val return_cheque_no:String,
val amount:String)
```

> Adding to Json Object

```
  var obj = JSONObject(myPreference!!.getJsonObject());
    Log.e("test Object add", obj.get("reciptDetail").toString())
    
    val paymentDetails : PaymentDetails = PaymentDetails(type, "", "", "","",false,"","",viewPaymentCash!!.etxt_amount.text.toString())
    myList.add(paymentDetails)
    val jsArray = Gson().toJson(myList)
    var obj2 = JSONObject(obj.get("reciptDetail").toString());
    
    obj2.remove("payment_details")
    obj2.put("payment_details",jsArray)
    
    Log.e("cash Object", obj2.toString())
```

Here I tried to add new Arraylist to existing JsonObject. Issue is that the final Json object is not what I am expecting. How can I solve that issue? Below I attched what I expected and what I got.

Expected

```
{"receiptNo":"fggff","todate":"4\/12\/2018","remark":"","payment_details":[{"account_no":" ","amount":"600","bank":"","branch":"","cheque_date":"","cheque_no":"","return_cheque_no":"","type":"Cash","return_type":false}]}
```

What I got from above code

```
{"receiptNo":"fggff","todate":"4\/12\/2018","remark":"","payment_details":"[{\"account_no\":\"\",\"amount\":\"600\",\"bank\":\"\",\"branch\":\"\",\"cheque_date\":\"\",\"cheque_no\":\"\",\"return_cheque_no\":\"\",\"type\":\"Cash\",\"return_type\":false}]"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Gson().toJson(myList)` returns a `String`.

You should build a `JSONArray` and add its elements. Then add this true array. This just works:

```
JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
array.add("test1");
array.add("test2");
JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
object.add("arr", array);
```

You also seam to be messing up JSON and GSON objects. Here I just used Gson objects.

Comment: Hi Now I added below code.but still I got same result   --

 val jsonArray = JSONArray()
            jsonArray.put(jsObject)

Comment: It works: `{"arr":["test1","test2"]}`. You're just doing something that makes a `toString()` somewhere. BTW you seam to be messing up JSON and GSON objects.

Answer (score 3):

as @shkschneider pointed `gson.toJson()` returns string value and you are adding that string directly to your json object, You need to convert it to json array and then add it.

```
JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(Gson().toJson(myList))
var obj2 = JSONObject(obj.get("reciptDetail").toString())
obj2.remove("payment_details")
obj2.put("payment_details",jsArray)
Log.e("cash Object", obj2.toString())
```